# React Redux Typescript - how to set types?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm having hard time setting the types for this function:

```
interface fetchedCountries {
    mergedArray?: [];
}

export const fetchCountries = () => {
    return (dispatch:(() => void)) => {
        console.log(dispatch)
        fetch(countryListJsonFile)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((jsonData: fetchedCountries) => {
                const array = Object.entries(jsonData)[0];
                const countries = array[1].map((el: any) => {
                    return el._id;
                }).sort();
                dispatch(setCountries(countries));
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.error(err);
            });
    };
};
```

it says that `setCountries expected 0 arguments, but got 1`.

I've tried to follow different guides, such as [this](https://dev.to/iamandrewluca/typed-fetch-response-in-typescript-1eh1), but I couldn't make it work.
I got lost. I want here to get rid of all the `any` types, and give the real ones.

The store has exported:

```
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

Here is the slice:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
    countryList: [],
};

const slice = createSlice({
    name: 'countryList',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setCountries(state, action) {
            state.countryList = action.payload;
        },
    },
});

export const { setCountries } = slice.actions;
export default slice.reducer;
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: How did you define setCountries?

Comment: setCountries is not stated in code.

Comment: As being stated in above comments, I would suspect that you haven't properly defined `setCountries()` action creator, I believe, it has to be something, like `const setCountries = (country: string) => ({type: YOUR_CORRESPONDING_ACTION_TYPE_HERE, country})`

Comment: I just added the slice. Please check my original question

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the problem lies in the parameter type of the returning function.

You returned `(dispatch: ((/* no parameters */) => void)) => {}` but you called `dispatch(setCountries(countries))` which has one argument `setCountries(countries)`. Setting correct number of parameters will fix, like `return (dispatch: ((something: unknown) => void)) => {}`.

Comment: `return (dispatch: AppDispatch) => {`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; I haven't used Redux much, so I haven't known the correct type for it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues here in your code are all related.  You need to properly define:

1. The type of `dispatch` in your `fetchCountries` function.
2. The type of the `payload` for `setCountries`.
3. The type of your state.
4. The type of your API response.

---

Incorrect or missing types higher up in the chain can cause issues further down.  For example, when you find yourself setting a type in a `.map()` callback like this:

```
array[1].map((el: any) => {
```

It means that the array itself (`array[1]`) has the wrong type.  So let's figure out where it's going wrong.

---

#### 1. Dispatch Type

@T.D. Stoneheart is correct.  The `expected 0 arguments, but got 1` error comes from calling `dispatch(...)`, not from calling `setCountries(...)`.

Your definition `dispatch:(() => void)` says that `dispatch` does not take any arguments.  This is obviously incorrect.

The good news is that you already have the correct type elsewhere in your code.  It is the `AppDispatch` which you exported from your store file.

```
export const fetchCountries = () => {
    return (dispatch: AppDispatch) => {
```

**This fix is enough to resolve all red-underlined errors.**  But there are some other mistakes and omissions that you may want to fix.

---

#### 2. Payload Type

If you don't explicitly set the type for `setCountries(state, action)`, then your payload type becomes `any`.  This is fine, but not ideal.  It says that "anything goes" which can make it hard to see genuine problems.

To assign the correct type to the action, import the `PayloadAction` utility type for redux toolkit:

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
```

And use it with the type of your payload, which is an array of countries.  Looking at your thunk, these seem to be `string`?:

```
reducers: {
    setCountries(state, action: PayloadAction<string[]>) {
        state.countryList = action.payload;      
    },
},
```

---

#### 3. State Type

Remember how I said that `any` can hide genuine problems?  If you followed step 2 then you should be seeing one of those now.

The assignment of `state.countryList = action.payload;` is giving an error:

> Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.

Your `state.countryList` has type `never[]` because it had an initial value of `[]` and that's all that TypeScript knows.  It doesn't know that this is supposed to be an array of country ids.  You can fix that by assigning a more accurate type to your `initialState.

Either do this:

```
const initialState = {
    countryList: [] as string[],
};
```

Or this:

```
interface SliceState { // can name it whatever
    countryList: string[];
}

const initialState: SliceState = {
    countryList: [],
};
```

Having a correct type here will make it much, much easier to use data that you've selected from your state because now `RootState` has the correct type for the `countryList` property.

---

#### 4. API Response Type

```
interface fetchedCountries {
    mergedArray?: [];
}
```

This type is saying that the JSON from your response is an object which maybe has a property `mergedArray` **which is an empty array**.  That's it.

I'm not sure what the actual data looks like, but perhaps something like this?

```
interface Country {
    _id: string;
}

interface FetchedCountries {
    mergedArray: Country[];
}
```

So now you don't need to use `(el: any)` because TypeScript already knows that `el` is a `Country` object.

```
.then((jsonData: FetchedCountries) => {
    const countries = jsonData.mergedArray
        .map(el => el._id)
        .sort();
    dispatch(setCountries(countries));
})
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mpDMXm)